# Scrape a web page that requires they give you a session cookie first

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-scraping, urllib2

I'm trying to scrape an excel file from a government "muster roll" database. However, the URL I have to access this excel file:

http://nrega.ap.gov.in/Nregs/FrontServlet?requestType=HouseholdInf_engRH&hhid=192420317026010002&actionVal=musterrolls&type=Normal

requires that I have a session cookie from the government site attached to the request.

How could I grab the session cookie with an initial request to the landing page (when they give you the session cookie) and then use it to hit the URL above to grab our excel file? I'm on Google App Engine using Python.

I tried this:

```
import urllib2
import cookielib

url = 'http://nrega.ap.gov.in/Nregs/FrontServlet?requestType=HouseholdInf_engRH&hhid=192420317026010002&actionVal=musterrolls&type=Normal'


def grab_data_with_cookie(cookie_jar, url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
    data = opener.open(url)
    return data

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()

#grab the data 
data1 = grab_data_with_cookie(cj, url)
#the second time we do this, we get back the excel sheet.
data2 = grab_data_with_cookie(cj, url)

stuff2  = data2.read()
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't the best way to do this. How could I do this more cleanly, or even using the requests library?

Comment: Are you aware of [urlfetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html) on App Engine?  If yes, what is your problem with `urlfetch`?  If no, check out the documentation and post back if you have further issues.

Comment: I would prefer to use urllib2, httplib etc. "directly" rather than through urlfetch so I can more easily reuse this code off App Engine. Granted that on App Engine I think these libraries are calling urlfetch anyway.

Comment: Question heavily updated, the problem was due to a cookie, not the rest of the script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) this is a trivial task:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/requests-is/awesome'
>>> r = requests.get(url)

>>> print r.cookies
{'requests-is': 'awesome'}
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work, unfortunately. I tried r1 = requests.get(url), r2 = requests.get(url,cookies=r1.cookies) but I get back the "landing page" in r2.text which means I'm not signed in, apparently. Love this library though, and looks like urllib3 is now functional within App Engine's sandbox.

Comment: Update, got it working. Didn't change the code, must have been older environmental variable crud messing up the test. Thank you!

Comment: It seems Original Poster wants to use a session cookie for subsequent requests.  With the Requests library you have suggested, this can be accomplished using Session() objects:  http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: I get `<RequestsCookieJar[]>` on Python3

Comment: Link has changed for Sessions(), this is what it is now: https://2.python-requests.org/en/v1.1.0/user/advanced/

Answer (score 3):

Using cookies and `urllib2`:

```
import cookielib
import urllib2

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
# use opener to open different urls
```

You can use the same opener for several  connections:

```
data = [opener.open(url).read() for url in urls]
```

Or install it globally:

```
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

In the latter case the rest of the code looks the same with or without cookies support:

```
data = [urllib2.urlopen(url).read() for url in urls]
```

Comment: Thank you, I've used these two libraries and gotten something working. Not sure how clean it is, but the question is edited to include the code above.