# hyper link url does not open without opening referring or parent page

Tags: session, url, cookies

-I have a job link

https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGWebHost/jobdetails.aspx?SID=%5eNJ9jpo3wVSbfK0NxdHECJijC2rWHbZl4%2f7afCQpgRyliOu2Weq1%2few7zT1iEt2vW&jobId=804091&type=search&JobReqLang=1&recordstart=1&JobSiteId=5011&JobSiteInfo=804091_5011&GQId=1640

-When I paste it to a browser url and hit enter, it results in

ErrMsg=NoCookieGetSessionIdForXML (The page does not load)

-However on the same browser if I open its referring or parent page

https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGWebHost/searchopenings.aspx?partnerid=25222&siteid=5011

-Then open a new tab, again on the same browser i go to the same link above

https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGWebHost/jobdetails.aspx?SID=%5eNJ9jpo3wVSbfK0NxdHECJijC2rWHbZl4%2f7afCQpgRyliOu2Weq1%2few7zT1iEt2vW&jobId=804091&type=search&JobReqLang=1&recordstart=1&JobSiteId=5011&JobSiteInfo=804091_5011&GQId=1640

this time the page is loaded successfully. I scrape the jobdetails urls (not the searchopenings url) and present them users on my own page. So can you please point me to how to achieve this? I have tried to trouble shoot and I think it may have to do with establishing session/cookies but still cant figure it all out. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need that cookie, so you need to generate that cookie from the landing page, acquire it, and then pass it to the page you want to get.  But exactly how you do that depends on the language you're coding your scraper in, which you've not mentioned here.  

I was very quickly able to find a solution for Python here on StackOverflow, and if you can't find what you're looking for, you may do well to ask a new question here, this time detailing the language you're performing the scrape in.

Comment: @RobWilkins Yes, I am using python for scraping, and can you please resend the link you mentioned? Much appreciate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754807/scrape-a-web-page-that-requires-they-give-you-a-session-cookie-first

Comment: @RobWilkins You guided me on the right path and so close to completion, i know now how to get cookies. Can you please also show how to add the cookies to an href link or <a> tag of a page so users can click to open it successfully. I have tried googling but unsuccessfully. Here is my page http://calgaryjobpostings.com/calgary-walmart  with the links that will not open unless you visit the landing page http://careers.walmart.ca/search-jobs/ first. Lastly, you have done enough for me to give my bounty points to, but I am not sure how when you only put your answers in comment box, you are humble!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the user is missing the appropriate cookie, as the comments and other answer says. However you don't have to go to such difficult lengths to pull in a cookie from a remote source, You can simply load a resource from that site in your html. Loading the resource will set the cookie in the users browser. This way when the user clicks on the link, they already have the cookie.

In the example below, I am loading the parent page in a hidden iframe, but if you find that an image also loads the cookie, you could just add that without bothering with an iframe.

```html
<iframe src="https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGWebHost/searchopenings.aspx?partnerid=25222&siteid=5011"
        style="display:none"></iframe>

<a
        href="https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGWebHost/jobdetails.aspx?SID=%5eHN7W7Qzw%2fF7gatWoBM6cE0ccmSO%2fucQkl75UsUrOYMnVywG9mXDR2RR1QJ0dl_slp_rhc_16&jobId=790214&type=search&JobReqLang=1&recordstart=1&JobSiteId=5011&JobSiteInfo=790214_5011&GQId=1640">Because the hidden iframe adds the cookie, this link works now!!</a>
```

Comment: tested working, it is genius! (i wrote a jquery script that attachs onclick event to the link and window.open('https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGWebHost/searchopenings.aspx?partnerid=25222&siteid=5011')                                                            So to set the required cookies on the user's browser but that also means open a tab on the user's browser (without their intension) - this is not a good practice. Thanks Mobius so much for sharing, you are brillian.)

Comment: glad I could help.